# Error Username and Pool information required while using Cognito with react app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-cognito

I am trying my hands on have a demo app on cognito with react.
To try things out I am trying the code which is present in this [git_repo](https://github.com/craig-feldman/aws-react-login)

But I am getting the Error `Username and Pool information required` . Which I don't know why.
I have a user pool and client id set up and using them in the code.
While creating the app client I also uncheck the box `Genereate client secret`.

The line where the error point to is  `props.setSession(session);`

```
import {
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
  CognitoUserSession,
} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import userPool from "../aws/UserPool";

type FormData = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

type LoginProps = {
  setSession: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<CognitoUserSession | null>>;
};

const Login = (props: LoginProps) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm<FormData>();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values) => {
    const user = new CognitoUser({
      Username: values.email,
      Pool: userPool,
    });

    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: values.email,
      Password: values.password,
    });

    user.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: (session) => {
        console.log("Login successful");
        props.setSession(session);
        history.push("/");
      },

      onFailure: (err) => {
        console.error("Login failed", err);
        setErrorMessage(`An error occurred while logging in: ${err?.message}`);
      },
    });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Welcome to this sample application <br /> Login below.
      </p>

      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="form">
        <input name="email" placeholder="email" type="email" ref={register} />
        {errors.email && errors.email.message}

        <input
          name="password"
          placeholder="password"
          type="password"
          ref={register}
        />
        {errors.password && errors.password.message}

        <button type="submit">Login</button>

        {errorMessage}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Can anyone help me out any steps that I am missing here?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Cognito User Pool set up but haven't linked it to an Identity Pool, you'll get this.

### How to Fix

1. Create a Cognito Identity Pool (all defaults are fine)
2. In the **Authentication Providers** for the Identity Pool, set the **User Pool ID** to your Cognito User Pool ID
3. In the same section, set the **App Client ID** to your **User Pools Web Client ID**

You'll probably need to update your `src/aws_exports.js` with the following key:

```
"aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "TheNewIdentityPoolID"
```

That's in addition to your other Amplify auth keys like:

```
"aws_user_pools_id": "UserPoolID",
"aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "WebClientId",
"oauth": {
  "domain": "domain",
  "redirectSignin": "http://localhost:4321",
  "redirectSignOut": "http://localhost:4321",
"
```

Comment: this didn't help me.... =(